# Need wireless drivers for Dell Latitude E5420

Tags: 12.10, drivers, dell

I have an Dell Latitude E5420 with Ubuntu 12.10. I need my wireless to work. Where can I can get the driver or how can I get the WiFi working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DELL Latitude E5420](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/Product/latitude-e5420) shows several wireless drivers:

- Wireless WLAN 1530 Half MiniCard  (Chipset BCM 4313)
- Intel WiMAX Link 6250 (Chipset Intel 6050 / Supported since Kernel 2.6.30)
- Intel WiFi Link 6200 (Chipset Intel 6000 / Supported since Kernel 2.6.30)
- Intel WiFi Link 6300 (Chipset Intel 6000 / Supported since Kernel 2.6.30)
- Intel WiMAX Link 6250 (Chipset Intel 6050 / Supported since Kernel 2.6.30)
- Intel WiFi Link 6205 (Chipset Intel 6000 / Supported since Kernel 2.6.30)

The full list of supported Intel wireless chipsets can be found [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi/?n=Downloads).

As you can see, the only driver left that needs an additional step to install is the Broadcom 4313. You can find most Broadcom Wireless drivers in [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-cards-bcm43xx-chipsets/60395#60395) .

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-cards-bcm43xx-chipsets/60395#60395You) also need to update your BIOS to include the latest firmware update since it **Fixes a
 64Bit UEFI OS installation issue**. You can find this upgrade in [the official site](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/latitude-e5420?driverId=PC2G7&osCode=ww1&fileId=3164205695&languageCode=en).

In case you are having a serious problem with one of the Intel wireless drivers, go to the [Intel Wireless download](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi/?n=Downloads) and download the one specific for your case. You can find more about which one you need by typing in the terminal `lshw -c network` and it will show you all network cards. The name of the card should appear there.

Now go to the site, download the one you need and follow the steps offered on the site to have your drivers working. I should mention that the ones operating on the 12.10+ are found in `/lib/firmware` and this are:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  337520 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  337572 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  689680 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  701228 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  695876 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  707392 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  150100 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  187972 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  340696 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  337400 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  454608 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  444128 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  677296 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  679436 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  469780 Nov  8 12:54 iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
```

As you can see, any wireless card with a chipset based on the ones on the list will be supported out of the box.